# single value in multivalued attribute in LDAP

Tags: java, ldap

I have an LDAP attribute which stores multiple values
ie, user details (like firstname, lastname, email address) are stored in one attribute with key value pair.

For example, attribute name='Testuser'. This 'Testuser' attribute as following multi values: firstname=test, lastname=testing
email=testing@xxx.com like this.

Now i want to modify firstname value alone using java code.
(I have searched many sites where i could find single attribute change using ModificationItem)

Here my code snippet:

```
DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
                  SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
                ctls.setReturningObjFlag(true);
                ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
                                String filter;
                filter = "(&(objectClass=myobjectclass)(apn=" + userName + "))";

                                 NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search("o=mydomain", filter, ctls);



while (answer.hasMore()) {
    SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)answer.next();
        Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
        String givenName = " ";
try {
                for (NamingEnumeration e = attrs.getAll(); e.hasMore();) {

                    Attribute attr = (Attribute) e.next();

                    System.out.println("Attribute name: " + attr.getID());



                    for (NamingEnumeration n = attr.getAll(); n.hasMore(); System.out

                            .println("value: " + n.next()));
}} catch (Exception err) {
givenName = " ";
}
  }
```

## I am getting following output:

```
Attribute name: apn
value: testuser
Attribute name: appropertycollection
value: Profile.Contact.ZipCode=46784157
value: Profile.Contact.State=7
value: Profile.Contact.MobileNum=4564545455
value: Profile.Contact.Password=12345
value: Profile.Contact.FirstName=David
value: Profile.Contact.Address=TestAddress456
value: Profile.Contact.Email=asde@xxx.com
value: Profile.Contact.LastName=lastname
```

Now I want to modify, "Profile.Contact.FirstName=David" value alone which is in a propertycollection Attribute.

Helps are really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a [javax.naming.directory.BasicAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/BasicAttribute.html), add all necessary attributes.

Then, follow the short tutorial here: [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ops/modattrs.html)

Please provide me with a short code snippet, so that we see what you agonize over.